# insert a primary key from one table as a foreign key to another table with php lastInsertId()

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am quite a newbie in PHP and MySQL so I need some help with correcting my code.

I have two tables - *person* and *grades*
First table has columns *id* (auto increment), *name*, *surname*.
Second one has columns *id* (auto increment), *personId*, *grade*.
*PersonId holds a foreign key which is a primary key as id in the person table.*

I insert data into the tables with the form then have php code to handle the data and insert it into my tables:

```
$firstName = $_POST['firstName'];
$lastName = $_POST['lastName'];
$grade = $_POST['grade'];

if ($firstName) {
$insertPersonSQL = <<<EOT
INSERT INTO person (firstName, lastName)
VALUES (:firstName, :lastName);
INSERT INTO grade (grade)
VALUES (:grade);
EOT;

$insertPersonStatement = $db->prepare($insertPersonSQL);
$insertPersonStatement->execute([
  ':firstName' => $firstName,
  ':lastName' => $lastName,
  ':grade' => $grade,
  ]);
}
```

Then I try to insert a id from person to grade as person_id using lastInsert() to get the id:

```
$insertIdSQL = <<<EOT
INSERT INTO grade (personId)
VALUES (:personId);
EOT;
$insertIDStatement = $db -> prepare($insertIdSQL);
$lastId = $db->lastInsertId();
$insertIDStatement -> execute([
  ':personId' => $lastId,
]);
```

However when I try to fill the form the person_id in the table grade gets the value of 0, the rest of the columns are ok.
When I debug and echo the value of $lastId it's showed correctly.

*What is wrong with the code? How to correct is so that the foreign key will be inserted correctly?*

Comment: My first idea to your issue is that the foreign key column person_id is not of the same type as the primary key. Please can you paste your database table columns?

Comment: both are int(11), I double-checked

Comment: do you have a default value for both columns (personId `and` grade) ?

Comment: Do you mean id and personId? If yes than both have "none" as default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why adding the `grade` without a `personId`? Isn't it better do do it in one query like this:

```
// Get params
$firstName = $_POST['firstName'];
$lastName = $_POST['lastName'];
$grade = $_POST['grade'];

if ($firstName) {
  // insert person
  $insertPersonSQL = <<<EOT
  INSERT INTO person (firstName, lastName)
  VALUES (:firstName, :lastName);
  EOT;

  $insertPersonStatement = $db->prepare($insertPersonSQL);
  $insertPersonStatement->execute([
    ':firstName' => $firstName,
    ':lastName' => $lastName
  ]);

  // insert grade
  $insertIdSQL = <<<EOT
  INSERT INTO grade (grade, person_id)
  VALUES (:grade, :person_id);
  EOT;
  $insertIDStatement = $db -> prepare($insertIdSQL);
  $lastId = $db->lastInsertId();
  $insertIDStatement -> execute([
    ':grade' => $grade,
    ':person_id' => $lastId
  ]);
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I just simply corrected my code so that I insert all data to the second table one time (both grade and personId) as you've recommended. And corrected the difference in spelling, person_id to personId.